# Using Assetic on CSS files which reference icon font files

Tags: symfony, font-awesome, assetic

I am trying to use Assetic and it's various filters to include an external icon font library (font-awesome).  The problem is that the CSS files reference font files, and the relative directories are not updated with the cssrewrite filter.  So, the CSS is loaded correctly, however, when it tries to load the font files, it gets a 404 response.  It appears that the cssrewrite filter is not adjusting the font file paths.

```
{% stylesheets filter="?uglifycss cssrewrite"
        "bundles/mybundle/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://github.com/bmatzner/BmatznerFontAwesomeBundle perhaps?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: i don't see the cssrewrite filter in your code ?

Comment: sorry, I had taken it out for debugging, but it is there.  It appears that cssrewrite doesn't affect font files?

Comment: can you edit your question ? (in order to have the code you really use, not the debugging code ...)

Answer (score 0):

I use bmatzner fontAwsome bundle (https://github.com/bmatzner/BmatznerFontAwesomeBundle) via composer and just include my scss or css and it seem to work fine with font and everything. I see it does not work if you dont have the cssrewriter added, then it does not have the fonts. Hope this helps.

SCSS/SASS

```
{% stylesheets
        'bundles/bmatznerfontawesome/scss/font-awesome.scss'
        filter="compass" filter='uglifycss' filter='cssrewrite' output='en/css/font-awsome.css'
        %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
```

CSS

```
{% stylesheets
        'bundles/bmatznerfontawesome/css/font-awesome.css'
        filter='uglifycss' filter='cssrewrite' output='en/css/font-awsome.css'
        %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
```

CONFIG

```
assetic:
  debug:          %kernel.debug%
  use_controller: false
  ruby: /path/to/ruby
  filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    compass:    ~
```

Added compass and ruby for sass